# Orchard Html widget import error

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7, orchardcms-1.8

After importing html widget content using the cms 'import tab' following error occurs: (Orchard 1.8.0)
(Error occurs only when selecting 'widgets' left menu item in dashboard)

Similar to http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/17992 but solution not in orchard 1.8 yet it appears?

---

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.

    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

    Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

    Source Error: 


    Line 20:                 @if (count > 0) {
    Line 21:                     int i = 0;
    Line 22:                     foreach (WidgetPart widget in widgets.Where(w => w.Zone == zone).OrderBy(w => w.Position, new Orchard.UI.FlatPositionComparer())) {
    Line 23:                         <li class="widgets-@(widget.LayerId == Model.CurrentLayer.Id ? "this" : "other")-layer widgets-layer-@widget.LayerId@(i == 0 ? " first" : (i == count ? " last" : ""))">
    Line 24:                             @using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost()) {

    Source File: c:\  ~\Modules\Orchard.Widgets\Views\WidgetPlacement.Zones.cshtml    Line: 22 

    Stack Trace: 


    [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
       Orchard.Widgets.Models.WidgetPart.get_LayerId() +35
       ASP._Page_Modules_Orchard_Widgets_Views_WidgetPlacement_Zones_cshtml.Execute() in c:\ ~\Modules\Orchard.Widgets\Views\WidgetPlacement.Zones.cshtml:22
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +199
       System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +104
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +90
       System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +256
       System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
       System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection) +277
       System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +91
       Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.Render(ShapeDescriptor shapeDescriptor, DisplayContext displayContext, HarvestShapeInfo harvestShapeInfo, HarvestShapeHit harvestShapeHit) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeTemplateStrategy\ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.cs:146
       Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass28.<Discover>b__15(DisplayContext displayContext) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeTemplateStrategy\ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.cs:133
       Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.<>c__DisplayClass5.<BoundAs>b__2(DisplayContext displayContext) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAlterationBuilder.cs:56
       Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Process(ShapeBinding shapeBinding, IShape shape, DisplayContext context) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:183
       Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Execute(DisplayContext context) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:87
       Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.ShapeExecute(Object shape) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:86
       Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.Invoke(String name, INamedEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:40
       Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:34
       CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , Object , Object ) +391
       ASP._Page_Modules_Orchard_Widgets_Views_WidgetPlacement_cshtml.Execute() in c:\ ~\Modules\Orchard.Widgets\Views\WidgetPlacement.cshtml:20
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +199
       System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +104
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +90
       System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +256
       System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
       System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection) +277
       System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +91
       Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.Render(ShapeDescriptor shapeDescriptor, DisplayContext displayContext, HarvestShapeInfo harvestShapeInfo, HarvestShapeHit harvestShapeHit) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeTemplateStrategy\ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.cs:146
       Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass28.<Discover>b__15(DisplayContext displayContext) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeTemplateStrategy\ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.cs:133
       Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.<>c__DisplayClass5.<BoundAs>b__2(DisplayContext displayContext) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Descriptors\ShapeAlterationBuilder.cs:56
       Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Process(ShapeBinding shapeBinding, IShape shape, DisplayContext context) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:183
       Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Execute(DisplayContext context) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DefaultDisplayManager.cs:87
       Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.ShapeExecute(Object shape) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:86
       Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.Invoke(String name, INamedEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:40
       Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\DisplayManagement\Implementation\DisplayHelper.cs:34
       CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object ) +439
       ASP._Page_Modules_Orchard_Widgets_Views_admin_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\ ~\Modules\Orchard.Widgets\Views\Admin\Index.cshtml:9
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +199
       System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +104
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +90
       System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +256
       System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
       Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.ThemeAwareness.<>c__DisplayClass7.<FindView>b__5(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, IViewDataContainer viewDataContainer) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Mvc\ViewEngines\ThemeAwareness\LayoutAwareViewEngine.cs:59
       Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.ThemeAwareness.LayoutView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Mvc\ViewEngines\ThemeAwareness\LayoutAwareViewEngine.cs:90
       System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +173
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
       Orchard.Mvc.Routes.HttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:159
       System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514928
       System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Widget XML content:

```
<!--Exported from Orchard-->
<Orchard>
<Recipe>
<Name>Generated by Orchard.ImportExport</Name>
<Author>admin</Author>
<ExportUtc>2014-08-15T00:51:30.8909012Z</ExportUtc>
</Recipe>
<Metadata>
<Types>
  <HtmlWidget Stereotype="Widget" DisplayName="Html Widget">
    <WidgetPart />
    <BodyPart />
    <CommonPart />
    <IdentityPart />
  </HtmlWidget>
</Types>
<Parts>
  <WidgetPart ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True" ContentPartSettings.Description="Turns a content type into a Widget. Note: you need to set the stereotype to &quot;Widget&quot; as well." />
  <BodyPart ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True" ContentPartSettings.Description="Allows the editing of text using an editor provided by the configured flavor (e.g. html, text, markdown)." BodyPartSettings.FlavorDefault="html" />
  <CommonPart ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True" ContentPartSettings.Description="Provides common information about a content item, such as Owner, Date Created, Date Published and Date Modified." />
  <IdentityPart ContentPartSettings.Attachable="True" ContentPartSettings.Description="Automatically generates a unique identity for the content item, which is required in import/export scenarios where one content item references another." />
</Parts>
</Metadata>
...cont..
```

Comment: What is the exception and the stack trace? What does the description of the widget look like in the import file?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I've updated to include stacktrace..and (part of) widget XML

Comment: Unfortunately, the import file is cut-off right where it would have begun to be interesting... Can you attach a debugger and find out what object is null?